# Discord JS, reply to certain user ID

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I want to make a command where the bot will only reply to a certain user id. But I'm confused how to make it so (FYI I'm new on JS)

```
const userID = '<@4608164XXX93150209>'

bot.on("message", function(message){
if(!message.author === userID)
{

if(message.content === 'psst')
    {
        message.channel.send('Hello there!');
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late to reply, but I had the same question and I used `msg.sender` instead of `msg.author`

```
const userID = "4608164XXX93150209"

bot.on("message", function(message){
if(!message.sender === userID)
{

if(message.content === 'psst')
{
    message.channel.send('Hello there!');
}
}});
```

Note that `msg.sender` is a string and not numeric

Answer (score 2):

I see that that people wrote different answers here, so ill just write the specific code you should use.

```
const userID = "The_user's_id";

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.id === userID) {
        message.react('emoji name or id');
    }
});
```

Note: to find the id of a user, just right click him and press "copy ID".

Answer (score 1):

That is just a string, not a guild member id.
Here do this.

```
const userId = message.guild.members.find(m => m.id === "USER ID HERE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the author id of the message with the `message.author.id` and then apply your logic.

```
let authorId = message.author.id;
//check author id here...

let mentionString = '<@!'+authorId+'>';
message.channel.send(mentionString+' pong');
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not your user ID. Your user ID can be found if you enable developer mode (User Settings -> Appearance -> Developer Mode) and then right click your name and click "Copy ID".

This ID should be a long sequence of numbers, and you literally just need to paste that for your ID. Don't add an @, or any <>, or anything else. An example of an ID is `198500238384693248`

Comment: its still not working :/ , now the bot wont reply to anyone